# CFLoop timeot error issue

Tags: database, coldfusion

I have some code that I'm borrowing form here: https://www.sitepoint.com/get-shorty-coldfusion/

I have all the cfcs and example code setup, as well as the database. When I attempt to run the code I get a cfloop error for the url shortener. Wondering if anyone can give me any ideas on why this may not be running.

```
The request has exceeded the allowable time limit Tag: CFLOOP. The error occurred in C:/ColdFusion2016/cfusion/wwwroot/URLS/add.cfm: line 5

<!--- keep trying to insert until successful --->
    <cfloop condition="len(shortlink) EQ 0">
        <cfset shortlink = application.oContent.insertContent(link)>
    </cfloop>
    <cfset message = "Your short URL is <a href='http://#cgi.server_name#:#cgi.server_port#/URLS/?#shortlink#'>http://#cgi.server_name#:#cgi.server_port#/URLS/?#shortlink#</a>">
```

Comment: It's at the top of the write up: The request has exceeded the allowable time limit Tag: CFLOOP. The error occurred in C:/ColdFusion2016/cfusion/wwwroot/URLS/add.cfm: line 5

Comment: if the link never gets created it would eventually time out.

Comment: Why would this be a `cfloop` and not a `cfif`?  Does the value of `link` ever change during the loop?

Comment: @snackboy if the link was created the `len()` would be > 0 and break out. Probably not the most ideal way, but _should_ work

Comment: @MattBusche The link is created in the database. I'm seeing 50 instances and the shortlink that was created however I'm not receiving a return.

Comment: @MattBusche - I guess if there was a possibility that the `application.oContent.insertContent(link)` didn't return anything back because it was busy or something, then the loop would be appropriate.  But the timeout, based on what we know at this point, is caused by the function not returning a string greater than zero.  Essentially, at least to me, the timeout error is masking the real problem which seems to be with the function, i.e. no matter how many times the function is called with the same parameters it's returning a zero length string.

Comment: @MattBusche - but all that said and in looking at the sitepoint link provided, I think that Jeff is going to have bump up the 'requesttimeout'.  From the page: _This loop will continue to run, generating new values and trying to insert them into the database, until it is successful and the value returned is not an empty string._

Comment: Isn't there a better way to check the len()?

Comment: @JeffG - if it's a string being returned, then len() is the way to go.  Based on the documentation that you linked from sitepoint, I think you are going to have to up your requesttimeout for that page/function.  `<cfsettings requestiontime='number of seconds'>` although this assumes that `application.oContent.insertContent(link)` actually works.

Answer (score 1):

To troubleshoot, change this:

```
<cfloop condition="len(shortlink) EQ 0">
<cfset shortlink = application.oContent.insertContent(link)>
</cfloop>
```

to this:

```
<cfset shortlink = application.oContent.insertContent(link)>
<cfdump var = "shortlink is #shortlink# and len(shortlink) is #len(shortlink)#">
```

If the length of the shortlink is 0, you have an infinite loop.  Then your focus should be on why shortlink is an empty string.

Having said all that, to repeat what was mentioned in the comments, this is an inappropriate place for a loop.  If it fails the first time, and you don't change anything inside the loop, it will always fail.